# Grizzly 2 connection caching

Tags: grizzly

Between versions 1.5 and 2, Grizzly had client connection cache functionality.

https://grizzly.java.net/docs/1.9/apidocs/com/sun/grizzly/connectioncache/spi/transport/OutboundConnectionCache.html

This is no longer there, nor can I seen any mention of why connection pooling/caching is no longer useful (the author of grizzly-thrift/grizzly memcached has seen fit to add it there, so I assume it is still useful).  Does anyone know why this was removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client-side connection pool is implemented as part of Grizzly 2.3.4:
http://mytecc.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/grizzly-2-3-4-client-side-connection-pool/

Comment: Holy moly, that's not what I was expecting.  Thanks!